# Does Sharepoint 2010 out of the box have rich right click context menus

Tags: sharepoint-2010

All my googling returned only information related to how to add additional right click features.

I swear somewhere I saw screenshots of MSS2010 being used where right clicking provided the menu to do various operations, versus having to use the ribbon, or worse that awful menu pictured here.

[image]

I was expecting this to all be drag drop... :(

I'm really disappointed with the lack of ajaxy-ness built into mss2010.  I can't believe every save/apply reloads the whole page.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking...

Comment: Not sure how to make it clearer.  I indicated in my question "rich" right click menus, since 2010 does have one or two areas where you can right click to view the same menu if you would click the down arrow next to the list item.

Comment: SharePoint runs in your web browser - where (AFAIK) its not possible to customize the right-click menu.  Perhaps if you give more detail about what you're looking to do, we can help you out.  As-is, your question sounds more like a rant.

Comment: Have you tried using SharePoint Designer?

Comment: @KyleTrauberman: Here is a sample of a page with right click context menus.  http://www.milonic.com/menusample27.php

Comment: Interesting.  It should be noted that those menus (which don't work in IE) aren't "true" right click menus.  It seems that the page is capturing the onRightClick event and showing a div at the mouse pointer.  Irregardless, the point is moot.  SharePoint doesn't have anything like that that I'm aware of.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman: I think I see the confusion.  I was always meaning an HTML created menu.  I never meant to imply the actual browser right menu would be altered. anyways, to your point; moot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint is a massive product. Microsoft appears to be adding and improving as much functionality as it can in each release.

A high priority of Microsoft for SharePoint 2010 was to redo the HTML for the end user pages. And it is much improved. The poorly formed, table heavy HTML of SharePoint 2007 now has more divs and unordered lists. However, you have stated that you do not like their design choices of the ribbon and full page refreshes. And you also do not like that UI improvements did not extend to system pages in the layouts directory.

SharePoint 2010 was released almost a year ago. Functionality changed during the beta, but it is unlikely that big changes will be introduced at this point. Your two best bets for getting your desired functionality are:

1. Create a [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) project that provides the functionality you want. If the project becomes popular, Microsoft might include it in the next release.
2. Based on [Sharepoint Feature Request](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/fd5e9dd6-96bf-495f-869e-79a06cc99096/), post your request to the SharePoint forums with a subject of "FEATURE REQUEST". If Microsoft agrees to your request, it could be included in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

MacroView specializes in document management, email management and knowledge management solutions based on Microsoft Office and Microsoft SharePoint.

MacroView DMF and MacroView Message add a new pane to Outlook which displays all the areas of the SharePoint environment for which you have access permission. The new pane in Outlook provides:

1. Searching across the SharePoint DM store with results displayed in Outlook
2. Formatted previews of files in SharePoint, without the need to download and open
3. **Extensive right-click menu for files and areas**
4. **Right-click to create new Libraries and Folders**
5. One-click access to your Favorite document libraries and folders in SharePoint
6. Automatic creation of Favorites – e.g. for Projects for which you are a timekeeper
7. Drag & Drop from everywhere to anywhere to save emails or attachments to ANY area where you have permission

Go [here](http://macroview.com.au) for more information